# My android studio artic fox version windows 64 bit was working fine but now I cant open it . tried reinstalling it. found some errors on studio.bat

Tags: android

studio.bat cmd error: I have been encountering this error. i have added JDK_HOME to the environment variables and wiped my temp folder , and added the latest android studio version available on the website . How do i solve this error.

```
2021-11-28 08:31:51,069 [    151]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:296)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt" to unnamed module @49ec2f72
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:253)
        at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:270)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.<clinit>(EdtInvocationManager.java:33)
        ... 4 more
2021-11-28 08:31:51,072 [    154]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292
2021-11-28 08:31:51,073 [    155]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 17.0.1; VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2021-11-28 08:31:51,073 [    155]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10

Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:296)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt" to unnamed module @49ec2f72
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:253)
        at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:270)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.<clinit>(EdtInvocationManager.java:33)
        ... 4 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1
```